# Selecting table row headers with xpath

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath

I am selecting table headers OK but need to use a similar method to return an index for an item in my row headers.

Here is my attempt...

```
def return_table_index():
        table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#main > table:nth-child(6)')
```

Part 1 column index (returns int correctly for 'table_header')

```
        table_headers = table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > th')
        index_of_column = None
        for i in range(len(table_headers)):
            if table_headers[i].text == table_header:
                index_of_column = i + 1
        print index_of_column
```

Part 2 row index (returns none, I want an int for 'row_header')

```
        row_headers = table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > th')
        index_of_row = None
        for i in range(len(row_headers)):
            if row_headers[i].text == row_header:
                index_of_row = i + 1
        print index_of_row
```

How can I update the xpath in part 2 to return the row index of say 3, which would be 4.

[Here is my sample data](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you basically need to get the first `td` in every row:

```
tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)
```

Comment: Thanks:) But that still produces 'none' for me, printing out 'index_of_row'. Do I have to look for '3' converted to str perhaps? Edit... I do! And it worked:)

Comment: I had to add +2 instead of +1 to account for the header row (I think)